# Which Python GUI IDE is the most widely used?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am still kind of new to programming and after playing around with a lot of languages trying to find which one worked best for me I stumbled across python and have been doing really well with it.

The only problem/concern I have is that I do not mainly want to do web development. I want to create desktop apps with nice GUis as well. Unlike most other programming languages that I have dabbled in python doesn't seem to have one definitive ide for this sort of thing which kind of sucks imo, especially since it's such a cool language.

I've searched and found quite a few IDEs that include GUI designers with code editing as well but I can't decide which one to use. Of those I am interested in the following

BlackAdder - http://www.thekompany.com/products/blackadder/
Pythoncard - http://pythoncard.sourceforge.net/
Boa Constructor - http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/
SPE - http://pythonide.blogspot.com/
Dabo (is it even an ide?) - http://dabodev.com/
Eric IDE - http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/index.html
Xrope - http://xrope.sourceforge.net/

I am not looking for opinions on which one is the "best" or anyone's favorite. I want to know which one is the most widely used and which one I would be able to find the most documentation on and get the most user support from whether it be via forums, here, community, etc..

P.S. If anyone cares to post any links to some documentation/tutorials with their answer it would be greatly appreciated.

P.P.S. Does anyone know if there are any plans for a larger company maybe thinking of creating a full fledged ide comparable to Delphi, Visual Studio for python in the foreseeable future? Would make things a lot easier IMO.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio to build IronPython GUI applications as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165375(v=vs.80).aspx

EDIT: You can now use pytools (http://pytools.codeplex.com/) to develop non-IronPython apps in VisualStudio.

Comment: Is ironpython the same as python as far as syntax is concerned? Or is it like learning a different language?

Comment: The syntax and the standard library are the same. But you need to know about the .NET framework. Also, you can't use C extensions on IronPython.

Comment: Now you can try this if you want to use VS as a Python IDE (non restricted to IronPython): http://pytools.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can also consider [PAGE](http://page.sourceforge.net/) and [PyQT](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) (Qt offers a GUI designers that is cross-platform and cross-language, PyQT just offers nice Python bindings)